# How to install only production dependencies in modern yarn when using node-modules linker

Tags: production, yarnpkg-v2

I'm using modern Yarn (v3.2.4 to be exact) which differs from Yarn Classic.

I'm using the `nodeLinker: node-modules` option in `.yarnrc.yml` so `/node_modules` are created, and dependencies are not saved to the repo.

I want to install only production dependencies (no devDependencies) but the `--production` flag isn't support in in Yarn 3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user *Bobby* mentioned in the other answer, it is possible to install only production dependencies by using the Yarn Workspace plugin.

This requires that the plugn be installed first: `yarn plugin import workspace-tools`.

Then install with: `yarn workspaces focus --production`.

Comment: No more plugin needed in v4

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `yarn workspaces focus --production` command. Check out the documentation [here](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/focus).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In addition, from [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774488/james) mentioned.

Now, For Yarn version `4.0.0` or more it's not necessary to import the plugin `@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools` because this plugin is already installed.

You can use this line to install the packages

```
yarn workspaces focus --production
```

Comment: Only use `yarn workspaces focus --production`. If you add `&& yarn install` all dependencies will be installed again.

Comment: @mrsimply I'm a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: The above commands fail for me. I have a mono repo and some packages depend on other local packages in the same repo. packages are referred using `"workspace:^"` in `package.json`. Could this be the reason. Any solutions?

Comment: @Achintha Can you try delete `yarn.lock` first?

Comment: It worked. The issue was some of the dev packages were missing which were required to build. So I first used the command without the `--production` flag and after the build I re ran the command with the flag. Now everything works